# SQL*Plus column separator

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm in `scott` user in SQL*Plus and is it possible in this `select` to separate columns by tabulation instead of the default space?

```
SELECT empno, ename, job FROM emp
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
SELECT empno '\t', ename '\t', job '\t' FROM emp
```

Instead of:

```
 EMPNO ENAME      JOB
```

---

```
  7369 SMITH      CLERK
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN
  7566 JONES      MANAGER
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN
  7900 JAMES      CLERK
  7902 FORD       ANALYST
  7934 MILLER     CLERK
```

I want more space between columns:

```
      EMPNO     ENAME           JOB
 ----------     ----------      ---------

       7369     SMITH           CLERK
       7499     ALLEN           SALESMAN
       7521     WARD            SALESMAN
       7566     JONES           MANAGER
       7654     MARTIN          SALESMAN
       7698     BLAKE           MANAGER
       7782     CLARK           MANAGER
       7839     KING            PRESIDENT
       7844     TURNER          SALESMAN
       7900     JAMES           CLERK
       7902     FORD            ANALYST
       7934     MILLER          CLERK
```

Comment: sorry to say but your question doesn't make sense. Your sql is invalid, you placed '\t' where column alias is specified. Please provide the output example you desire to achieve. If you are talking about formatting columns in SQL*Plus command interface, you should look at sqlplus commands, not sql.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **COLUMN** command ([see SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12013.htm#BACHCABF)) and format your report according your wish

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution would be:

set colsep ' '

Answer (score 0):

As sqlab already pointed out you need the COLUMN formatting options which are in SQL*PLUS.

Since the docs aren't very readable, here is what you need:

```
COLUMN EMPNO FORMAT A10
COLUMN ENAME FORMAT A16
COLUMN JOB FORMAT A9
```

If you need to do it in regular SQL you can use this:

```
SELECT rpad(empno, ' ', 11) empno
,      rpad(ename, ' ', 17) ename
,      job
FROM   emp
```

Comment: Do you need more help? If not, please close this question by marking it as answered.